# I don't know what that error means and how to solve this. I want to add Country key and France value to the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement, console

```
dictionary_of_spliting = {"Food":"Honey",
                          "Trash1":"some",
                          "Trash2":"some",
                          "Trash3":"your",
                          "Thing":"resorces"}

for keys in dictionary_of_spliting:
    if var <= 12:
        dictionary_of_spliting["Country"] = "France"
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "C:\Users\IK\PycharmProjects\More sting methods.py", line 20, in <module>
   for keys in dictionary_of_spliting:
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Comment: Why are you looping at all? Just use the `dictionary_of_spliting["Country"] = "France"` line if you want to associate the string "Country" with "France". The error is happening because you're modifying the dictionary while iterating it using the `for` loop.

Comment: ```var``` is not defined

Comment: @Carcigenicate, why didn't you add that as an answer? (genuinely wondering)

Comment: @queste Because their intent is unclear. I don't like posting answers unless I think I have a good understanding of the question. I don't currently understand why they're looping though, so I don't feel comfortable posting an answer until their intent is clearer. Note that the current answer solves the immediate issue, but the code they recommend still doesn't make any sense. Why loop to do a dictionary lookup?

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying a dict while iterating through it - this is not allowed, as it breaks the underlying iterator.

You can replace

```
for keys in dictionary_of_splitting
```

with

```
for keys in list(dictionary_of_splitting)
```

to make a copy of the entries and prevent this issue. You can also use dictionary_of_splitting.keys() if using python2